# Travis CI build is not starting

Tags: reactjs, docker, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I am trying to learn the tool Travis CI , and thus I made a react project which is run inside a docker container. I have pushed the code on git-hub with all the necessary files. Even after making the .travis.yml file with no errors, after pushing the code , Travis is not triggering the build of the app.

Below is the code repository structure :

[my code repo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7iQA.png)

This is code of the file Dockerfile.dev :

```html
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json .

RUN npm install 
RUN chmod -R a+rwx node_modules

COPY . .

CMD ["npm","run","start"]
```

This the code in .travis.yml file :

```html
sudo: required

services: 
  - docker    

before_install: 
  - docker build -t mydockerreact -f Dockerfile.dev .

script:
  - docker run mydockerreact npm run test
```

I have tried almost everything in this file but the build is not triggering on the CI tool

Answer (score 1):

You have to login to travis with you GitHub account and activate your repository first before pushing the travis.yml file. check [here](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/tutorial/#to-get-started-with-travis-ci-using-github)

And add language to your travis.yml if no language is specified travis will think it's ruby project and gives 'No Gemfile found, skipping bundle install' error. So if u don't want to add any language you can use generic

```
language: generic
services: 
  - docker    

before_install: 
  - docker build -t mydockerreact -f Dockerfile.dev .

script:
  - docker run mydockerreact npm run test
```

Comment: I have already done the login to travis to github and activated the repo, 
Not after adding language too, it is not working.
No build is starting

Comment: Can you share your GitHub repo ?

Comment: good for using generic language when using docker otherwise you have to make default install to be skipped eg. nodejs, python etc.

Answer (score 0):

After some research I found out that I was using travis-ci.org and that's why it wasn't building it.
I switched to travis-ci.com and it worked absolutely fine.